# CSS div with position absolute and scrolling

Tags: html, css, scroll, position, absolute

I would like these positions and dimensions for the `div` elements of my HTML document:
[image]

In each of these `div` elements, if the content is too large to fit into them (a lot of text for example), I want to have a vertical scrollbar to scroll the content.
I would like a scrollbar per `div` and I don't want a unique scrollbar for the web page.

So, I would like to keep the positions and dimensions of my `div` fixed.
I just want to have the possibility to scroll in these `div` if necessary.

I wrote this CSS sheet:

```
div
{
    position: absolute;
}
div.header
{
    background-color: red;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
}
div.menu
{
    background-color: green;
    top: 10%;
    left: 0%;
    width: 20%;
    height: 80%;
}
div.main
{
    background-color: blue;
    top: 10%;
    left: 20%;
    width: 80%;
    height: 80%;
}
div.footer
{
    background-color: yellow;
    top: 90%;
    left: 0%;
    width: 100%;
    height: 10%;
}
```

I wrote this HTML document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Title</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="header">Aaa bbb ccc ddd eee fff ggg hhh iii jjj kkk lll mmm nnn ooo ppp qqq rrr sss ttt uuu vvv www xxx yyy zzz. Aaa bbb ccc ddd eee fff ggg hhh iii jjj kkk lll mmm nnn ooo ppp qqq rrr sss ttt uuu vvv www xxx yyy zzz.</div>
        <div class="menu">Aaa bbb ccc ddd eee fff ggg hhh iii jjj kkk lll mmm nnn ooo ppp qqq rrr sss ttt uuu vvv www xxx yyy zzz. Aaa bbb ccc ddd eee fff ggg hhh iii jjj kkk lll mmm nnn ooo ppp qqq rrr sss ttt uuu vvv www xxx yyy zzz.</div>
        <div class="main">Aaa bbb ccc ddd eee fff ggg hhh iii jjj kkk lll mmm nnn ooo ppp qqq rrr sss ttt uuu vvv www xxx yyy zzz. Aaa bbb ccc ddd eee fff ggg hhh iii jjj kkk lll mmm nnn ooo ppp qqq rrr sss ttt uuu vvv www xxx yyy zzz. Aaa bbb ccc ddd eee fff ggg hhh iii jjj kkk lll mmm nnn ooo ppp qqq rrr sss ttt uuu vvv www xxx yyy zzz. Aaa bbb ccc ddd eee fff ggg hhh iii jjj kkk lll mmm nnn ooo ppp qqq rrr sss ttt uuu vvv www xxx yyy zzz. Aaa bbb ccc ddd eee fff ggg hhh iii jjj kkk lll mmm nnn ooo ppp qqq rrr sss ttt uuu vvv www xxx yyy zzz. Aaa bbb ccc ddd eee fff ggg hhh iii jjj kkk lll mmm nnn ooo ppp qqq rrr sss ttt uuu vvv www xxx yyy zzz. Aaa bbb ccc ddd eee fff ggg hhh iii jjj kkk lll mmm nnn ooo ppp qqq rrr sss ttt uuu vvv www xxx yyy zzz. Aaa bbb ccc ddd eee fff ggg hhh iii jjj kkk lll mmm nnn ooo ppp qqq rrr sss ttt uuu vvv www xxx yyy zzz. Aaa bbb ccc ddd eee fff ggg hhh iii jjj kkk lll mmm nnn ooo ppp qqq rrr sss ttt uuu vvv www xxx yyy zzz.</div>
        <div class="footer">Aaa bbb ccc ddd eee fff ggg hhh iii jjj kkk lll mmm nnn ooo ppp qqq rrr sss ttt uuu vvv www xxx yyy zzz. Aaa bbb ccc ddd eee fff ggg hhh iii jjj kkk lll mmm nnn ooo ppp qqq rrr sss ttt uuu vvv www xxx yyy zzz.</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The result is not the one expected when there is a lot of text:
[image]

As you can see a scrollbar is missing in each `div` element.
So, I can't read all the text content in the `div` elements.

How can I get the expected result please?

Thank you.

Best regards.

---

I tried the [Cédric](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17684809/c%c3%a9dric) solution.

CSS:

```
body{
  height:100vh;
  margin:0;
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}
.container{
  overflow-y:scroll;
}
.content{
  height:1000px;
}
.header{
  width:100%;
  height:10vh;
  background-color:red;
}
.menu{
  width:20%;
  height:80vh;
  background-color:green;
}
.main{  
  width:80%;
  height:80vh;
  background-color:blue;
}
.footer{
  width:100%;
  height:10vh;
  background-color:yellow;
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Title</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container header">
            <div class="content"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="container menu">
            <div class="content"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="container main">
            <div class="content"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="container footer">
            <div class="content"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Result:

[image]

As you can see a scrollbar is missing in some `div` elements.
It happens when the window is small.

Answer (score 0):

Here I set width (% but could be vw, viewport-percentage width) and height of every elements (vh, viewport-percentage height)

I also used `overflow-y:scroll` on the 4 container.

```css
body{
  height:100vh;
  margin:0;
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}
.container{
  overflow-y:scroll;
}
.content{
  height:1000px;
}
.header{
  width:100%;
  height:10vh;
  background-color:red;
}
.menu{
  width:20%;
  height:80vh;
  background-color:green;
}
.main{  
  width:80%;
  height:80vh;
  background-color:blue;
}
.footer{
  width:100%;
  height:10vh;
  background-color:yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container header">
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
<div class="container menu">
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
<div class="container main">
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
<div class="container footer">
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work perfectly. I edited my question to explain what happens.

Comment: It might be due to the use of an old browser because even in a 100x100 window (tested on updated chrome 105.0.5195.102) I get the 4 scrollbar, you can try checking if the browser knows every css rules used in the inspector

Comment: By the way you can make a working example in your question by using the `<>`  button on top to make a code snippet, don't hesitate to edit your question to use it, it motivates people to answer by seeing the result of your code easilly

Comment: @YuGiOhJCJ I just realize that it may work in your example but you don't see the right scrollbar on the smallest elements because it don't have place to show it because the window is not tall enough. Try adding some elements to try if you can scroll